# Why is this condition-based list comprehension not working?

Tags: python, list, python-2.7, list-comprehension

I want to create a list from an existing list after removing all duplicates.
Program works if I use a "for loop" but nothing happens if I use a list comprehension.

```
#use for loop
l=[1,2,2,3,1,1,2]
j=[]

for i in l:
    if i not in j:
        j.append(i)

print l
print j


#using list
l1=[1,2,2,3,1,1,2]
j1=[]

j1=[i for i in l1 if i not in j1]

print l1 
print j1
```

Comment: If you just want to remove duplicat you can convert list to set i,e `set(l)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The expression `[i for i in l1 if i not in j1]` is evaluated and then assigned to *j1*. So during the evaluation *j1* stays empty.

BTW: An easy was of removing duplicates is to pass the list to the [set](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#func-set) function and then to the [list](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#func-list) function if you need a list:

```
j1=list(set(l1))
```

Answer (score 0):

`j1` is `[]` at the start and isn't updated at intermediate points within the list comprehension. Could do this instead of list comprehension though:

```
l1=[1,2,2,3,1,1,2]
j1=list(set(l1))

print l1 
print j1
```